# Performance: Reference vs. value as function parameters

Tags: c++, c, variables, parameters, reference

I have got a function which I need to pass a value to for read-only purposes only.

For example:

```
unsigned short strlen(String str)
{
  short i = 0;
  while(str[i] != '\0')
    i++;
  return i;
}
```

As you can see, I do not want to change the original value I work with, I only need to read its length. Would it - in terms of performance - be better to replace the parameter `String str`, which is making a copy of the original variable, by a reference like `String &str`?

Comment: I approach it like so - Pass by value if your function needs a copy, pass by reference if the parameter is required and you don't need a copy, pass by pointer if the parameter is optional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it - in terms of performance - be better to replace the parameter String str, which is making a copy of the original variable, by a reference like String &str?

Yes, it would. Instead of creating a copy, which you do not seem to need here, a reference would be bound. Since you are not modifying the object, a reference to `const` would be better:

```
unsigned short strlen(String const& str)
//                           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Isn't `const String &` by far the more common spelling? I suspect they are the same, I just wonder why you'd write it in that order.

Comment: @delnan: I prefer this style because of uniformity (the `const` necessarily has to come after if you want to declare a `const` pointer, like `int* const`) and because it is easier to figure out what is going on with template type deduction

Comment: @delnan it is more common, and it means the same, it's just that `string const` reflects semantics better (`const` applies to whatever is on its left side, unless there's nothing there.)